# Macrobenchmark is failing due to null result in Google sample

Tags: android, macrobenchmark

I am trying to learn Jetpack benchmark. By reviewing this google sample : https://github.com/android/performance-samples/tree/main/MacrobenchmarkSample

One of classes includes following method :

```
private fun MacrobenchmarkScope.clickOnId(resourceId: String) {
        val selector = By.res(packageName, resourceId)
        if (!device.wait(Until.hasObject(selector), 2_500)) {
            fail("Did not find object with id $resourceId")
        }

        device
            .findObject(selector)
            .click()
        // Chill to ensure we capture the end of the click span in the trace.
        Thread.sleep(100)
    }
```

And it has been called like : `clickOnId("launchRecyclerActivity")`

The string is a resource :

```
<string name="launchRecyclerActivity">RecyclerView</string>
```

And RecyclerView is an item in MainActivity :

```
BenchmarkActivityButton(name = "RecyclerView") {
            launchActivityWithTrace<NonExportedRecyclerActivity>()
        }

@Composable
    fun BenchmarkActivityButton(name: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
        TextButton(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            onClick = onClick,
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        ) {
            Text(name)
        }
    }
```

The problem is this line returns null : `val selector = By.res(packageName, resourceId)`

And therefore I receive following exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.test.uiautomator.UiObject2.click()' on a null object reference
at com.example.macrobenchmark.clickslatency.ClickLatencyBenchmark.clickOnId(ClickLatencyBenchmark.kt:189)
at com.example.macrobenchmark.clickslatency.ClickLatencyBenchmark.access$clickOnId(ClickLatencyBenchmark.kt:40)
at com.example.macrobenchmark.clickslatency.ClickLatencyBenchmark$simpleViewClick$2.invoke(ClickLatencyBenchmark.kt:64)
at com.example.macrobenchmark.clickslatency.ClickLatencyBenchmark$simpleViewClick$2.invoke(ClickLatencyBenchmark.kt:51)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmark$measurements$1$tracePath$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:193)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt$macrobenchmark$measurements$1$tracePath$1.invoke(Macrobenchmark.kt:167)
at androidx.benchmark.perfetto.PerfettoCaptureWrapper.record(PerfettoCaptureWrapper.kt:90)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmark(Macrobenchmark.kt:167)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode(Macrobenchmark.kt:301)
at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.MacrobenchmarkRule.measureRepeated(MacrobenchmarkRule.kt:106)
at com.example.macrobenchmark.clickslatency.ClickLatencyBenchmark.simpleViewClick(ClickLatencyBenchmark.kt:51)
```

How it can be resolved?